# What is Wrong with my Query?

Tags: sql, subquery

I am working on a project for a data bootcamp that I am in, and I am working with three tables. Within these tables, I am trying to find a little more information about the users in this data set. Some of the questions I would like to answer are...

1. How many users use more than one browser in their daily life?
2. What are the most popular browsers used besides firefox?
3. What is the most popular browser used amongst users who use multiple browsers?

Attached is an overview of my table (ignore the crap code) 
[image: data set and tables]
This is the query I am having problems with:

```
select user_id, q2, q3, q4
from survey
where q2 = '0' or '1' and q3 = '0' or '1' or '2' or '3' and q4 = '0' or '1' or '2' or '3' or '4' or '5'
```

I want to pull up the named values for q2, q3, q4. How do I write this correctly so that it pulls the data in one set? I would like to pull it in one set so that I can export and import into excel and pivot the data.

Comment: Please Show an example how your Output should Looks like

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _named values_ and also, that does not look like valid SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: `and` has precedence over `or`: use `in`: `where q2 in ('0','1') and q3 in ('0','1','2','3') and q4 in ('0','1','2','3','4','5')`.

Comment: @JonathonOgden each question (q2, q3, q4) has a list of values like 0,1,2,3, etc that are used in place of text. For instance 0 for q2 means "No, I only use Firefox" - this is provided on another document. I just want to output all of the results for Q2, Q3, and Q4. 

The program I am using is Wagon - it's a tool we are using to learn SQL.

Comment: So you are wanting to retrieve the text for each question. In which case, there will be another table you will have to `join` to, where the `q` column values are _keys_ (links) to the other table. Do you know which table stores the question text?

Comment: @JonathonOgden unfortunately none of the tables contain the question text. I had to use this document to retrieve the text for each question:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160304073326/https://testpilot.mozillalabs.com/testcases/a-week-life-2/aggregated-data.html

It's a poorly designed exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Misunderstanding of operator precedence - If you have both `and` and `or` make sure you wrap properly with `()`..
2. Compile error - between each `or` you must specify again the comparison. `q3 = '0' or '1'` won't work -> change to `q3 = '0' or q3 = '1'`

So:

```
select user_id, q2, q3, q4
from survey
where (q2 = '0' or q2 = '1')
and (q3 = '0' or q3 = '1' or q3 = '2' or q3 ='3')
and (q4 = '0' or q4 = '1' or q4 = '2' or q4 = '3' or q4 = '4' or q4 = '5')
```

Now, a **nicer way** to do this is to use `in`

```
select user_id, q2, q3, q4
from survey
where q2 in ('0','1')
and q3 in ('0','1','2','3')
and q4 in ('0','1','2','3','4','5')
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This helped a lot. "In" is new for me, looks like I will be using it a lot in this project thanks to you and trincot.

Comment: I don't see how your #1 is a logical error, more like a misunderstanding of operator precedence.

Answer (score 3):

The thing that is wrong with your query is that you cannot write `q2 = '1' or '2'`. It is invalid syntax. Use `in` instead:

```
where q2 in ('0','1') and q3 in ('0','1','2','3') and q4 in ('0','1','2','3','4','5')
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used "in" yet. This is a great.